# Do the moderators get paid & Shall we reappoint the moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Having high interest in any field is fine, but moderators seem to be doing it more as a Job than as a Hobby.

Some moderators are really annoying new users by down Voting a lot. If the content is not good fine. But many moderators or those who down vote fail to provide necessary comments to soothe the one who answers.

Finally, shall we reappoint the moderators? They've been since 2012. What do you say?

Interested users who would like to keep this community up and going well are welcomed. The nominees will voted by the users (we can create voting forms for them).

As those moderators who've been doing the same job since 2012 might have got tired, as can be seen by decreased efficiency in maintaining the site to the expected standards.

Comment: One problem with this site is lack of effective/adequate moderation by the entire moderation team *and* community by large. But currently this burden is mainly on only one moderator. So the main problem is lack of a community of active/dedicated users who contribute not only to the site content but also moderation. Don't forget that many of the moderation tools can be used by all users, and the so called "moderators" are only given some extra privileges for exception handling. See [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Comment: A fresh mod team is the most needed change in this site or else it is clearly doomed. The current singly active mod has alienated many users already , even the high rep users which were promising earlier are now inactive on the site. In short a single mod is responsible for not being able to build a cohesive community. I am glad that even new users can feel this.

Comment: So what shall we do or can we do @Islam

Comment: Moderators aren't the only ones who vote down. There is only one active moderator right now, so if a post gets more than one downvote, it means it is also being downvoted by other people.

Comment: You asked a significant interesting question which could be the inquiry of many users, hence a nice response could be constructive..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On beta sites, [anyone with 125 reputation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) can downvote posts.  Anyone.  Downvoting and commenting are hardly moderator-only abilities.

Or, to put it another way, *[everone on the site is a moderator](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1461/22)*, and downvoting and commenting very much *are* moderator abilities.

Instead of just jumping to conclusions about who downvoted you and why, try to figure out how you can improve your answer (see help centre page on "[How can I write a good answer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)", as well as the relevant meta post "[How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/598/22)" for advice).  The onus is always on the original poster to write a good post in the first place, but what voters consider good is not necessarily the same thing as what the poster considered good.

As for the rest of your questions:

- No, moderators do not get paid.  They are volunteering their time like pretty much everyone else on the site.
- Community-run moderator elections are unlikely to happen until the [community demonstrates itself healthy enough](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1429/22) to participate in them (i.e. graduates from beta); this is far from the case right now.
- [Moderator reappointment is unlikely](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/841/22) unless there is a compelling need for the Community Team to do so (e.g. if an existing moderator voluntarily resigns or is involved in blatant abuse).

The moderators were [chosen directly by the Stack Exchange Community Team](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), but for the most part, their powers are the same as those available to any other community user (with enough reputation), simply accelerated.  When it comes to deciding how to curate the site, they are users like any other with their own opinions and making their own judgements.

If you find yourself at odds with a moderator decision, or for that matter a decision by any community user, fine.  [That happens](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1312/22).  It's a side-effect of being in a community made up of different people, after all.  But moderators are expected to [lead by example](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/); if you disagree with the example a moderator is setting, you still need to ask yourself if what you're trying to do on the site is actually what the site was intended for.

Immediately calling for moderator replacement just because they "might" be tired (and because someone downvoted you) is unlikely to be taken seriously by the Community Team.

Comment: What you have regurgitated is the correct theory but   the fact is that the goal of a cohesive community like the ones at jse , cse is very far away,i am not asking to stop practing , you are doing it tediously but it has to be done with grace without offending others

Comment: And mostof the questions on mod behaviour are either supressed or deleted, hence people dont find it worth it to do it.

Comment: @Islam Moderator-complaints tend to get deleted if they are (a) abusive or (b) posted to the wrong place.  Meta is *full* of complaints against moderators that are neither suppressed nor deleted, but that still doesn't mean anything if they're not particularly *compelling*.

Comment: hey @goldPseudo so can we ask the direct stack exchange community to re run that selection of moderators? What do you say?

Comment: @Wiser Sure, you can *ask*.  But like I said, they're unlikely to take you seriously unless you make a particularly compelling argument, and to date I've seen absolutely no compelling reason to warrant such a reappointment.

Comment: @servantofWiser People have appealed to the StackExchange community as a whole a few times about the moderators here. Each time, it has been found that the moderators are acting appropriately and everybody else is acting inappropriately.

Answer (score 2):

The downvotes are coming simply because of the nature of religion. If an answer or a question disagrees with someone's deeply embedded belief, the automatic and easiest way to retaliate is to downvote.

You will see downvotes when there is a discrepancy between views from different sects. You will see downvotes when an answer goes completely against cultural values or what you've been "taught" as a child. For example, I don't believe the Qur'an has a scientific miracle on embryology - it does indeed talk about epigenesis (known to Aristotle 1000 years before) but epigenesis is not modern embryology (far from it). If I was to use that as an answer to a embryology question (with sufficient research) I'd still get downvoted because many people just don't want to listen/read that critical thought.

People forget that this is not a place for truth answers, opinions, and belief. It's a (or supposed to be) a repository of high level (maybe research level) questions on the religion itself and NOT its implementation. But the majority of the questions don't reflect it.

Back to the question. The problem simply lies in the nature of this SE website and there is nothing we can do about it. The problem ISNT the downvotes, its a much deeper problem that is driving away high rep users and attracting low quality questions/answers.

I don't think its a moderator problem. In fact I think MORE moderation is needed. I think there needs to be much more aggressive moderation so that the site becomes what it was originally intended for.

Comment: well dear I understand ur feelings, but using a word "aggressive" is aggressive. U know. It may be phrased as "strict moderation" if u wish.